# We have to make prediction of daily complaints through past complaint data , so which model will be appropriate for this?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, data-science, forecasting

I'm working on data that have daily records of complaints and sales records and these all seasonal data related to time series . So i have to apply model on this data so that can predict the future days complaints on behalf of previous data. So I have to apply only regression models for that or not?... I'm new to it so don't have any idea about that so please guide me. Thanks.